# How to serialise 2 table usinq sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I do i serialize this 2 table ..

**Table 1** `DOCINF`

```
DOCSKI , APPUKI, DOCINF_TYPE, NUMCHARS, DATETM

11  , ABC1234, ACK , 256, 20180219
```

**Table 2** `UDINF`

```
UID, DOCSKI, APPQUAL, APPVALUE

1 , 11, ABC, 1234
2 , 11, DEF, 5678
3 , 11, GHI, 9012
```

How do i do the query to come out the result like below ,

```
APPUKI, DOCINF_TYPE, NUMCHARS, DATETM, < APPVALUE >, <APPVALUE>, <APPVALUE>

ABC1234, ACK , 256, 20180219 ,1234 ,5678, 9012
```

Try so many query but did't get the result.

```
SELECT APPUKI,
  DOCINF_TYPE,
  NUMCHARS,
  DATETM,
  a.appvalue,
  b.appvalue,
  c.appvalue
FROM docinf
LEFT OUTER JOIN udinf a
ON docinf.docski = a.docski
LEFT OUTER JOIN sp_udinf b
ON docinf.docski = b.docski
LEFT OUTER JOIN sp_udinf c
ON docinf.docski = c.docski
AND a.uid   <> b.uid
AND c.uid   <> c.uid order BY docinf.docski ;
```

Thanks;

Comment: What is `sp_udinf`? Are you looking for [`pivot`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `GROUP BY`  with a `JOIN`  with `MAX ( CASE block )` for each column.

Another option is `PIVOT` - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c44d6/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCINF
    (DOCSKI int, APPUKI varchar2(7), DOCINF_TYPE varchar2(3), NUMCHARS int, DATETM int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO DOCINF (DOCSKI, APPUKI, DOCINF_TYPE, NUMCHARS, DATETM)
         VALUES (11, 'ABC1234', 'ACK', 256, 20180219)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE UDINF
    (UID_ int, DOCSKI int, APPQUAL varchar2(3), APPVALUE int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO UDINF (UID_, DOCSKI, APPQUAL, APPVALUE)
         VALUES (1, 11, 'ABC', 1234)
    INTO UDINF (UID_, DOCSKI, APPQUAL, APPVALUE)
         VALUES (2, 11, 'DEF', 5678)
    INTO UDINF (UID_, DOCSKI, APPQUAL, APPVALUE)
         VALUES (3, 11, 'GHI', 9012)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT appuki,
       docinf_type,
       numchars,
       datetm,
       MAX (CASE
              WHEN appvalue = 1234 THEN appvalue
            END) AS APPVALUE_1,
       MAX (CASE
              WHEN appvalue = 5678 THEN appvalue
            END) AS APPVALUE_2,
       MAX (CASE
              WHEN appvalue = 9012 THEN appvalue
            END) AS APPVALUE_3
FROM   docinf a
       JOIN udinf b  -- or LEFT OUTER 
         ON a.docski = b.docski
GROUP  BY appuki,
          docinf_type,
          numchars,
          datetm
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c44d6/4/0)**:

```
|  APPUKI | DOCINF_TYPE | NUMCHARS |   DATETM | APPVALUE_1 | APPVALUE_2 | APPVALUE_3 |
|---------|-------------|----------|----------|------------|------------|------------|
| ABC1234 |         ACK |      256 | 20180219 |       1234 |       5678 |       9012 |
```